# How to issue an SAS that inherits from a policy

Tags: r, azure-blob-storage

I made an Access Policy for my blob container like this
[image]

how do I make an SAS that inherits from this?  When I go to the Shared Access Tokens screen there's no reference to policy.

Ideally, I'd like to know how to do this using the `R` `AzureStor` library in addition to how to do it in the portal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as Portal is concerned, I believe the functionality to use an access policy to create a SAS token is not implemented.

You can use Azure Storage Explorer instead. It has this support.

[image]